# How to switch to/restore an open application on windows 7 with a custom keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been having a good look around the web but can't seem to find a solution to this.

Recently I've been using a piece of software called ConEmu that has a shortcut of "ctrl+'" which allows me to switch to it quickly from any other open application. I'd like to be able to do the same for other programs such as my web browser and text editor.

I know you can use alt+tab or win+number to switch between open programs on Windows, but I'd like to be able to setup specific keyboard shortcuts as well. I thought this would be a pretty simple thing to do, but apparently not.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create shortcut to the application on your desktop (lnk file).
2. In the shortcut properties set up desired hotkey. Well, Windows allows very limited set of key modifiers, but it's working.